# How to add *.i files in bazel BUILD script file

Tags: opencv, bazel

I want to add **features2d** into the build script for building opencv with bazel. [Here](https://github.com/ApolloAuto/apollo/blob/master/third_party/opencv2.BUILD) is the build script which this module to be added.

I was able to add a few other modules except for **features2d** because inside this module it consists of some *.i files (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/2.4.13.2/modules/features2d/src)

Problem is that there is no rule so as to include *.i in the src directory.

```
cc_library(
    name = "features2d",
    srcs = glob(["modules/features2d/src/**/*.cpp"]),
    hdrs = glob([
        "modules/features2d/src/**/*.hpp",
        "modules/features2d/src/**/*.h",
        "modules/features2d/include/**/*.hpp",
        "modules/features2d/include/**/*.h"
    ]) + [
        ":module_includes",
    ],
    includes = [
        "modules/features2d/include",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        ":imgproc",
        ":flann",
    ],
)
```

This is the error is trowing:

```
@opencv2//:modules/features2d/src/generated_32.i' does not produce any cc_library srcs files (expected .cc, .cpp, .cxx, .c++, .C, .c, .h, .hh, .hpp, .hxx, .inc, .S, .s, .asm, .a, .lib, .pic.a, .lo, .pic.lo, .so, .dylib, .dll, .o or .pic.o).
```

If anybody has an idea how this can be done, really helpful.